# adjacent matrix for graph In python fron XLS file

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python and I want to make an adjacent matrix to use it as a graph.
I got a file .XLS which has the vertices and edges. you can see it on it pinture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbVGG.png)

```html
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("Graph_data.XLS","rb")
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
rows = []
for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    columns = []
    for j in range(sheet.ncols):
        columns.append(sheet.cell(i, j).value)
    rows.append(columns)

rows
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("Graph_data.XLS","rb")
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
l1 = []
l2 = []
for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    columns = []
    for j in range(sheet.ncols):
        columns.append(sheet.cell(i, j).value)
    l1.append(columns[0])
    l2.append(columns[1])

import numpy
l1 = numpy.asarray(l1, dtype=int)
l2 = numpy.asarray(l2,dtype=int)
uniques = list(numpy.unique(l1))+list(numpy.unique(l2))

harlinton = {}
for i in numpy.unique(uniques):
    a =list(l2[numpy.where(l1 == i)[0]])
    #b =list(l1[numpy.where(l2 == i)[0]])
    c = list(numpy.unique(a))
    harlinton[i] = c
    
harlinton
```